# excel solver and lp_solve API

Tags: excel, linear-programming, solver, lpsolve

I have a mixed integer/binary linear programming problem, the free version of excel solver can find a solution that satisfies all the constraints. however, the lp_solve API that I call from C++ could not find a solution. I suspect that excel solver simplifies the problem. So far I locate 2 parameters in excel solver option: mip gap and constraint precision. the former is set to 1%, i set the lp_solve's mip gap to 1%, but I do not know what is the equivalent constraint precision in lp_solve. Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: It may be more appropriate to try a different MIP solver. If you export the problem as an MPS file you can try out a few solvers at [NEOS](https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/index.html). In my opinion tinkering with options like feasibility tolerances is very seldom a wise approach.

Comment: thanks @ErwinKalvelagen, i will probably try CPLEX solver.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, I tried the CPLEX solver on NEOS server, it solves and gave me exactly same results as excel solver. So now it came down to why lp_solve does not work for the same problem.

Comment: Cplex is a stronger MIP solver than LpSolve.

Comment: Are you aware that lpsolve implicitly assumes that the decision variables are non-negative?